# Python Iterar sobre JSON anidado con valores variables

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

Hola amigos disculpen alguno podria ayudarme a iterar sobre este json que me regresa la peticion que hice con requests pero ya intente con items() y values()
pero nada mas me manda errores o por lo menos decirme que estoy haciendo mal estaba por ejemplo intentado acceder a User-Agent

Ya intente con

```
   for i in json:
       for j in i:
```

y nada

Tambien intente de la manera

```
    for key,value in json.items()
         for key2,value2 in value.items()
```

Aqui dejo el diccionario

```
            json = {
                    "args": {
                    "curso": "python", 
                    "nombre": "eduardo"
                    }, 
                    "headers": {
                    "Accept": "*/*", 
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
                    "Connection": "close", 
                    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
                    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
                    }, 
                   "origin": "201.141.214.165", 
                   "url": "http://prueba.html"
                    }
```

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Para acceder por ejemplo, al valor de la clave User-Agent, no necesitas realizar ninguna iteración, basta con usar lo siguiente:
json["headers"]["User-Agent"]

Answer (score 0):

Debería de funcionar, aquí te dejo un código funcionando:

```
json = {
    "args": {
        "curso": "python",
        "nombre": "eduardo"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
    },
    "origin": "201.141.214.165",
    "url": "http://prueba.html"
}
for (key, val) in json.items():
    if type(val) is dict:
        for (key1, val2) in val.items():
            print("{}.{}: {}".format(key, key1, val2))
    else:
        print("{}: {}".format(key, val))
```

Específicamente funciona para tu conjunto de datos, pero supongo no siempre será el mismo, así que aquí otra forma que funciona independientemente de la estructura del diccionario.

```
json = {
    "args": {
        "curso": "python",
        "nombre": "eduardo"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
    },
    "anidado": {
        "anidado1": {
            "a11": {
                "a111": "hola"
            }
        },
        "anidado2": {
            "a21": {
                "a211": {
                    "a2111": "hola otra vez"
                }
            },
            "a22": "hola bye"
        }
    },
    "origin": "201.141.214.165",
    "url": "http://prueba.html"
}

def print_properties(value, parent):
    if type(value) is dict:
        for (key, val) in value.items():
            if type(val) is dict:
                print_properties(val, parent + '.' + key)
            else:
                print("{}: {}".format(parent + '.' + key, val))
    else:
        print("{}: {}".format(parent, value))


for (key, val) in json.items():
    print_properties(val, key)
```

Por cierto, en Python no existen los JSON's, se les llama diccionarios, pero sí vienen siendo lo mismo un array asociativo.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias Benjamín Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
def printjs(js,parent):
for (key,val) in js.items():
        if type(val) is dict:
            printjs(val,parent+'.'+key)
        else:
            print("{}:{}".format(parent+'.'+key,val)[1:])
printjs(json,'')
```

Comment: Considera explicar y dar contexto de la respuesta que has entregado para tener una mejor visualización de la misma ;)

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas iterar por el diccionario si lo que quieres es acceder a un elemento concreto y sabes la "ruta" (entendiendo por ruta en qué clave del diccionario se haya, y en qué sub-clave dentro de esa clave).

Dices que quieres acceder al User-Agent. Pues entonces basta escribir:

```
agent = json["headers"]["User-Agent"]
```

Lo que estabas haciendo mal en tu caso era supone que todos los valores dentro de tu json eran a su vez diccionarios. No es el caso, pues por ejemplo para la clave "origin" el valor es directamente una cadena ("201.141.214.165") mientras que para otras claves como "args" el valor sí que es un diccionario.

Puedes hacer una función recursiva que busque una clave dada dentro de un diccionario, y que si el valor asociado con esa clave es otro diccionario, que lo busque también dentro de él. Sería así:

```
def buscar(json, clave):
    for k, val in json.items():
        # Si encontramos la clave, retornamos su valor
        if k == clave:
            return val
        # Si no, podemos mirar si el valor asociado es otro diccionario
        if type(val) == dict:
            # Llamada recursiva a sí mismo
            encontrado = buscar(val, clave)
            if encontrado:
                return encontrado
    return "" # En caso de que no lo encontremos
```

Ahora podemos probar a usar esta función para encontrar cualquier clave que aparezca en algún lugar del diccionario o de cualquiera de sus sub-diccionarios (con cualquier nivel de anidación). Te retornaría sólo el primer resultado que aparezca, o una cadena vacía si no aparece.

```
print(buscar(json, "origin"))
print(buscar(json, "User-Agent"))
print(buscar(json, "curso"))
print(buscar(json, "No existe"))
```

Imprimiría:

```
201.141.214.165
python-requests/2.21.0
python
```